# Java: Getting a 503 Error when trying to read webpage using HTMLUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I've been testing out HTMLUnit and I wanted to see if I could get a value off of some websites.

After trying it on: https://rsbuddy.com/exchange?id12934, I seem to get some 503 error, however.

It seems to be some kind of confliction with CloudFlare's IUAM.

I've looked around and found [this site](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/help-web-crawler-java-503-response-code.109093/) in which someone had the same problem as I have. The community told the poster that HTMLUnit could resolve their problem and it seems like it did in the end, however, no solutions came of it.

What my code looks like at the moment is simply:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange?id12934");
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

This outputs:

```html
INFO:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      color: #404040;
      text-align: center;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 1em;
      color: #404040;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    #spinner {
      margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
      display: block;
    }
    .attribution {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes bubbles {
      33%: {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
        transform: translateY(10px);
      }
      66% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
    @keyframes bubbles {
      33%: {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
        transform: translateY(10px);
      }
      66% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
    .bubbles {
      background-color: #404040;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      margin: 2px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      -webkit-animation: bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: bubbles 0.6s 0.07s infinite ease-in-out;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
      var a = function() {
          try {
            return !!window.addEventListener
          } catch (e) {
            return !1
          }
        },
        b = function(b, c) {
          a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)
        };
      b(function() {
        var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
        a.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout(function() {
          var s, t, o, p, b, r, e, a, k, i, n, g, f, MASOuLk = {
            "eMSgRDgS": +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]))
          };
          t = document.createElement('div');
          t.innerHTML = "<a href='/'>x</a>";
          t = t.firstChild.href;
          r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
          t = t.substr(r.length);
          t = t.substr(0, t.length - 1);
          a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
          f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');;
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS -= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (+[]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS -= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (+[]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS += +((!+[] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS *= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS *= +((+!![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS *= +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
          MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS += +((!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![] + []) + (!+[] + !![] + !![] + !![]));
          a.value = parseInt(MASOuLk.eMSgRDgS, 10) + t.length;
          '; 121'
          f.submit();
        }, 4000);
      }, false);
    })();
     //]]>
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
          <noscript>
            <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
          </noscript>
          <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
            <div>
              <div class="bubbles"></div>
              <div class="bubbles"></div>
              <div class="bubbles"></div>
            </div>
            <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> rsbuddy.com.</h1>
            <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
            <p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
          </div>
          <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="c4f4252fa3ee7b54a685f74ba192d186" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1468717381.249-GOgXzrnovV" />
            <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer" />
          </form>
        </div>


        <div class="attribution">
          <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=iuam" target="_blank" style="font-size: 12px;">DDoS protection by CloudFlare</a>
          <br>Ray ID: 2c39c577c5bb41cf
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>

Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable for https://rsbuddy.com/exchange?id12934 at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:570)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:395) at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303) at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:450) at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:435)
at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:20) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Is there a way of using HTMLUnit that would allow this to connect to the site?

Answer (score 1):

There is a time wait for checking browser version, i am sure that if you:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
```

First set your browser version. Then run the line to get page:

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange?id12934");
```

Followed by few options:

i. Set the time to wait:

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);
```

or

```
while(page.asText().contains("Checking your browser before accessing")){
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);             
}
```

ii. Use Thread.sleep() instead of wait for JS:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);// replace with this code.
```

Finally print it out with:

```
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post but i just had this same problem but solved it.

It is a jdk issue, java 8 doesn't have TLS 1.3 enabled by default. And some sites require TLS 1.3 to work. TLS 1.3 was not even implemented until java 8u261. (i didn't know oracle had java 8 updates after java 8u202 until now). Now i am using java 8u311 released in October 19, 2021, all you need to do to make it work is set one of these jvm properties :

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2" or -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2"

More information here https://www.java.com/en/configure_crypto.html

Comment: would u please post how I can change those jvm properties you posted? have no idea, my OS is windows 7. DO i Just need to add the 2 lines below to /lib/security/java.security file: 

java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2" java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2" appreciate it dante

Comment: In my case when i start a jar i use the command: java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2" -jar myJar.jar

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved the issue for me.