# HtmlUnit bypassing cloudflare DDOS and cookies required

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrape a page that uses Cloudflare, until recently this was possible with no issues. However as of yesterday, I'm encountering 503 (the ddos protection page). And today it transitioned to simply 403's. Inspecting the response I can see that the page is requesting I enable cookies. I am currently using HtmlUnit to perform the scrapes and I have the BrowserVersion set to Chrome.

here is my current attempt:

```
    private HtmlPage scrapeJS(String targetUrl) throws ScrapeException {
        Log.verbose("Attempting JS scrape ...");
        WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(css);
        client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(insecureSSL);
        client.setCookieManager(new CookieManager());
        client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

        HtmlPage page;

        try {
            page = client.getPage(targetUrl);
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e){
            Log.verbose("JS scrape resulted in " + e.getStatusCode());
            throw new ScrapeException(source, e);
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new ScrapeException(source, e);
        }

        return page;
    }
```

I should mention that this fails both the cookies check and 503s on my desktop, but it passes the cookies check not on my laptop (which is a mac).

I have looked around a little but most posts dealing with HtmlUnit seem a bit dated and the solutions, such as waiting for background JS, does not work nor does changing the user agent between firefox and chrome.

Comment: Maybe its due to the SSL

Comment: Does it fail even for the first request or only after several requests?

Comment: Hey Erik, 

Did you find a solution here? I am having the same problems :)

Comment: @SpasBobchev I did not, ended up finding an API for the site instead that bypasses this problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69760898/2751894

just use one of these jvm properties:

-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2" or -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2"

Comment: Don't post duplicate answers. If the answer there answers the question here, flag/vote to close this post linking that post. Otherwise, tailor your answer to this specific question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30205436)